# Accessing MemberInfo in parent class

Tags: c#, .net

I have an Attribute class, a parent and it's child:

```
class DisplayInfo : Attribute {
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public DisplayInfo(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

class A {
    [DisplayInfo("This is Alma")]
    public string Alma {set;get;}
}

class B : A {
    [DisplayInfo("This is Beta")]
    public string Beta {set;get;}
}
```

I would like to get a list from properties and it's values of instance B. This is my code:

```
IEnumerable<MemberInfo> sourceProperties = from source in sourceType.GetMembers().ToList()
  where source.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property
  select source;
// where sourceType is typeof(B)

DisplayInfo di;
foreach (MemberInfo mi in sourceProperties) {
  di = (DisplayInfo)mi.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayInfo>();
  ret.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}",
  di != null
    ? di.Name
    : mi.Name,
  B_instance.GetType().GetProperty(mi.Name).GetValue(B_instance, null)));
}
```

It's working for all of direct fields in class B but of course doesn't lists the fields in A. How could I achieve them?

Answer (score 1):

Use the other overload of GetCustomAttribute:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138307(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// parameter: inherit => true
di = (DisplayInfo)mi.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayInfo>(true);
```